# elasticsearch lib can not add commons-beanutils and commons-collections Simultaneously

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch, jar, elasticsearch-plugin

I made a native java plugin for elasticsearch, and I imported the `net.sf.json` jar in my plugin. So I added the following jar in `path\elasticsearch-2.0.0\lib`:

```
commons-beanutils-1.8.0  
commons-collections-3.2.1  
commons-lang-2.5  
commons-logging-1.1.1  
ezmorph-1.0.6  
json-lib-2.4-jdk15
```

But when I run `./elasticsearch`, it shows the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: jar hell!  
class: org.apache.commons.collections.ArrayStack  
jar1: D:\Program Files\elasticsearch-2.0.0\lib\commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar  
jar2: D:\Program Files\elasticsearch-2.0.0\lib\commons-collections-3.2.1.jar  
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.JarHell.checkClass(JarHell.java:267)  
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.JarHell.checkJarHell(JarHell.java:185)  
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.JarHell.checkJarHell(JarHell.java:86)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:156)  
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:270)  
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:35)  
Refer to the log for complete error details.
```

Referenced checkClass, I guess it because that `commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar` and `commons-collections-3.2.1.jar` both have path `org\apache\commons\collections`.

How can I deal with it?
And is there other way to add extra jar for plugin in elasticsearch?

Comment: Are you using Maven to build and manage dependencies?

Comment: yes, I manage dependencies like this:  

    `<dependency>
         <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
         <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
         <version>2.4</version>
         <classifier>jdk15</classifier>
    </dependency>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My temporarily way to solve this question is **remove** the folder `org.apache.commons.collections` in commons-beanutils jar.
because I find that the class files in this folder are also contained in commons-collections.
Also the way is very not smart, it works, and I just need remove and add to lib file once.

Or use other version of commons-beanutils that does not contain collections forder, like version 1.9.2

**UPDATE**
Thanking @Val's thinking, the better `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <classifier>jdk15</classifier>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Maven, you can use [dependency exclusions](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html) in your `pom.xml` for the `json-lib` artifact:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <classifier>jdk15</classifier>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

What will happen is that the compile-time dependencies for `json-lib` will not be used. Note that you run the risk of creating conflicts since your version of `json-lib` might depend on different versions of `commons-beanutils` and `commons-collections`, but that's worth a try.

**UPDATE**

Then you simply need another exclusion for your direct `commons-beanutils` dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: It still not work. `"caused_by" : {
          "type" : "no_class_def_found_error",
          "reason" : "org/apache/commons/collections/map/ListOrderedMap"}`.    the way to temporarily work it is in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34012050/elasticsearch-lib-can-not-add-commons-beanutils-and-commons-collections-simultan/34013939#34013939), also it is very not smart.

Comment: no, collections folder still in `commons.beanutils` jar. See my update, thanks for your thinking in exclution.